# Please fill in my sound design survey (on animation)- you get 100 free flacs effects!

Tags: animation, design, survey

Just click the link, fill the survey and whehey i get some answers you get some samples, nice!

http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/KPV5JMM

thank you my fellow geeks

Answer (score 0):

So what are you striving to achieve with this survey?

I answered it but I found it to be rather misguided about what "sound design" is. Unless you happen to be an engineering student specializing in audio signal processing and I would understand your interest towards hyperreal sound synthesis and its applicability in media sound production. That is, a purely technological viewpoint to "sound design".

Comment: I agree.... Also weird to be generalising about an entire genre of film - its the directors call on how stylised or natural sounding any particular moment or overall aesthetic is... 

Comment: Totally agree. I don't really understand this survey. It's always different, and depends on the overall vision of the film. And btw - survey is not really well constructed - while doing surveys like this, you rather want to have the answer from the person reading it, not already suggesting the answer in the question, that you're looking for. It's faking the result. After reading the question, you allready set the mindset for "hypher realism"